# Using Garage Band sounds for commercial purposes

Tags: audio, garageband

Im making a Drumming app for the iphone and the ipod touch.
I was searching for good drum samples around the internet, but couldn't find anything fitting. Then i thought of garageband and its drum kits which contained the samples that i needed.

Will apple allow me to use the garageband's kit sounds separatly and for commercial purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can't. The [linked](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2931) article specifies exactly that you can't:

> to create your own original music
>   compositions or audio projects. You
>   may broadcast and/or distribute your
>   own music compositions or audio
>   projects that were created using the
>   Audio Content, however, **individual
>   audio loops may not be commercially or
>   otherwise distributed on a standalone
>   basis**, **nor may they be repackaged** in
>   whole or in part as **audio samples**,
>   sound effects or music beds."

(emphasis mine)

You can create as many songs as you want using all the sounds you have in the loops and sell the songs. But you will be packaging the sounds (or repackaging) as audio samples of your application which seems to be forbidden.

Comment: tnx, i thought it wouldn't be possible either, but i just had to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

No you can not - what you ask is akin to distributing the loops on a standalone basis as loops. But you're free to incorporate them into your own commercial works. There's an Apple KB article on it: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2931

Comment: No you can't. Yes you can make music, all that you want, but you can't repackage a sound or audio sample as is. (Which a *good drum sample* is)

Comment: I stand corrected - I went looking for the link after my first post and didn't reread it all.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know if Apple has any means to "notice" that ;)