# Apple Loops Copyright

Tags: garageband, copyright

Let's say I used some Apple Loops in a 5 min contest video that's being sold to the contest host (So he can show a reference for this years contest). Might be uploaded on youtube + their site..

I have two apple loops and one of my own samples playing on and off, but the Apple Loops have more playtime and they're at a low volume when people speak and such which is for the most part of the video. They fade out come in again etc.

These two audio files (Apple Loops) including my own, still in the original form/format from Apple and I have only mixed them and arranged in one track.

Other than that, no further self compositions were added.
And if it makes any difference my own sample is played in the middle, so one Apple Loop in the beginning section and one at the end section.

- Is this to repackage them as music beds (Illegal)?
- Or is the "soundtrack" original (Am I cleared)?

Comment: Did you see this older question that covers Apple Loops quite thoroughly? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49748/license-and-royalty-specifics-for-appleloops-in-logic

Answer (score 3):

The license for GarageBand (accessible from `About Garageband`) states:

> H. GarageBand Features and Support. Except as otherwise provided, you
>   may use the Apple and third party audio loop content ("Audio
>   Content"), contained in or otherwise included with the Apple Software,
>   on a royalty-free basis, to create your own original soundtracks for
>   your video and audio projects. You may broadcast and/or distribute
>   your own soundtracks that were created using the Audio Content,
>   however, individual samples, sound ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼ sets or audio loops
>   may not be commercially or otherwise distributed on a standalone
>   basis, nor may they be repackaged in whole or in part as audio
>   samples, sound libraries, sound effects or music beds.

If you include these loops in a larger work (i.e. you mix them in and they don't simply stand alone as a single sound), then you can sell or re-distribute that work under the terms of your license to those sounds.  You cannot distribute the loops themselves on their own as you would then be reselling / repackaging the  Apple loops.

If you were to create a composition that contained solely a single Apple loop, and tried to distribute that, it would not be allowed by the license.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201808

Comment: Here's the thing. During that video, and apple loop/jingle comes first, then my own sample from my private library and then another apple loop/jingle...

Comment: That should still be ok.  It's a larger work which contains the apple loops, and the reason Apple gives you the loops is so that you can use it to create larger things.

Comment: I see I see okay