# May I register with ©copyright my songs made mixed with just apple loops or must be copyleft, creative commons, royalty free, etc...?

Tags: music, garageband, license, copyright

I'm starting to use GarageBand for making music, and I have several songs of my own; but I find xtremly funny mixing loops, so, I have another ones that are only loops mixes.

I know that they are royalty free if you mix the loops, I've read a lot, and I didn't find the answer to my question in the web. (February 2016)

I want to sell the songs, but I don't know if I can put my ©Copyright stamp in the only loop ones.

Can somebody help me understand the licensing terms?

Comment: Did you find Apple's licensing terms? What part are you uncertain about? See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129932/apple-loops-copyright for some details on this...

Comment: I understand both answers. But my question - let's see if I am more accurate -, is, if I have a song named HelloWorld.mp3 made with legal apple loops, mixing several ones, (I know that's legal), but... May I put the © symbol relative to this song in the album? Or must I give another kind of royalty free licence, like copyleft, creative commons, free royalties, etc... Hope it is better explained. Thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: You can put the copyright symbol on anything - but you'd need a lawyer to advise you based on exactly where you live on whether you gain anything or risk anything by doing so. Apple provides these sounds royalty free so you should be at little risk from them as long as your mixing up of multiple sounds is clearly evident to someone listening to your works.

Comment: Thanks @bmike.... That's what I needed to hear. I'm registering only de composition, but remarking that I have no rights over the loops, and the album name says everything clear about. (Music made with apple loops) Hope it is enough. I don't know how to vote your help...

Comment: I find this question should be addressed to Apple support directly.

Answer (score 2):

Royalty free means you can release music that incorporates the loops without paying or crediting anyone. The only thing you can't do is sell the loops separately.